# IF Formula that Copies and Pastes into Separate Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an event that recognizes companies that excel in community service initiatives and doing the registration in Excel.
We are able to 'comp' a certain amount of tickets to encourage guests to attend.

I'd like to create a formula (or macro, not really sure which would be best) that basically does this:

IF a value in column M (number of comp'ed tickets) is either 1 or 2, copy the entire row (w/ attendee's name, contact info, etc.) and paste into a worksheet in the same document called "Comp'ed Tickets" on the next available row moving from the top-down. If there are no comp'ed tickets, do nothing.

This way, I'm effectively creating a separate sheet for tickets that have been comp'ed to have at our registration table.

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe you can filter on column M or create a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

I think a macro would be best. Have you tried this on your own? Do you have some sample code we can work off of?

Essentially you want to loop through column M, input an if statement into your loop that says if the value of the specific cell in column M is 1 or 2 then take the row of that cell, copy it and paste it to the next available row (same as selecting the last row in the workbook and doing ctrl + up then down arrow) on whichever sheet you want.